# What is the difference between default scaffold and nifty:scaffold?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to generate a layout which I can use between `my rails webapp` and mobile versions. I have been using `nifty-generator`, but it says the generated files are identical to what was generated by rails3 new application creation.

What's the major difference between `default scaffold` and `nifty:scaffold`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you visit the Github page (https://github.com/ryanb/nifty-generators) for the project under 'Troubleshooting and FAQs' it answers a few questions including this one. The response given there is:

> One of the primary differences is that nifty:scaffold allows you to
>   choose which controller actions to generate.
>
> ```
> rails g nifty:scaffold post name:string index new edit
> ```
>
> There are a few changes to the generated code as well, such as no XML
>   format by default.
>
> It also offers support for HAML, Shoulda, and RSpec.

Once you get a handle on the code that Rails needs in its RESTful controllers I would highly recommend using Inherited Resources (https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources) instead. It really helps DRY up your controllers.

Comment: I know am late to the party here but the [inherited_resources](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources) gem is not longer actively maintained as stated in the github page.